# Trying to set up SMS reminders via my web application

Tags: php, web, cron, sms, host

I am trying to have an SMS sent as a reminder to the users of my web application. I am not too familiar or good with cron jobs. I know that I have to set one up, I don't think that I did it effectively though.

I am not sure if my path is correct, how could I test that? Also, should I set it to every minute or should I set it to once a day. What is the difference?

Would this work if the path is correct?

[image: screenshot from bluehost- I don't know if the path is correct either]

```
<?php
//This was based upon http://glennstovall.com/blog/2013/01/07/writing-cron-jobs-and-command-line-scripts-in-codeigniter/ with modifications for Easy!Appointments by Craig Tucker, 7/18/2014.

class Reminders extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->model('settings_model');       
    $this->load->model('reminders_model');

    // Set user's selected language.
    if ($this->session->userdata('language')) {
        $this->config->set_item('language', $this->session->userdata('language'));
        $this->lang->load('translations', $this->session->userdata('language'));
    } else {
        $this->lang->load('translations', $this->config->item('language')); // default
    }
}

public function index() {
    if(!$this->input->is_cli_request()) {
        echo "This script can only be accessed via the command line" . PHP_EOL;
        return;
    }

    $d = 3; //Number of days out for the reminder
    $timestamp = strtotime("+".$d." days");
    $appointments = $this->reminders_model->get_days_appointments($timestamp);
    $baseurl = $this->config->base_url();
    $company_name = $this->settings_model->get_setting('company_name');
    $appointment_link = $this->config->base_url().'index.php/appointments/index/';

    if ($d == "1") {
        $notice = "One more day until your appointment.";
    } else {
        $notice = $d." more days until your appointment.";
    }

    $msg = '';

    if(!empty($appointments)) {
        foreach($appointments as $appointment) {
            $aptdatetime=date('D g:i a',strtotime($result["start_datetime"]));
            $startdatetime=date('l, F j, Y, g:i a',strtotime($appointment->start_datetime));
            $config['mailtype'] = 'text';
            $this->email->initialize($config);
            $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
            $this->email->to($appointment->customer_email);
                if (!empty($appointment->customer_cellurl)){
                    $phone = $appointment->customer_phone_number;
                    $phone = preg_replace('/[^\dxX]/', '', $phone);         
                    $this->email->bcc($phone.$appointment->customer_cellurl);
                }
            $this->email->from($appointment->provider_email, $company_name);
            $this->email->subject($notice);
                $msg .= $company_name."\r\n";
                $msg .= "REMINDER: Your appointment with ".$appointment->provider_first_name." ".
                    $appointment->provider_last_name." is on ".$startdatetime."\r\n";
                $msg .= "\r\n";
                $msg .= "If you have had a good experience, let others know! Please review me at:\r\n";
                $msg .= "www.healthgrades.com/review/XGVRC\r\n";
                $msg .= "\r\n";
                $msg .= "To edit, reschedule, or cancel your appointment please click the following link:\r\n";
                $msg .= $appointment_link.$appointment->hash."\r\n";
                $msg .= "\r\n";
                $msg .="To attend your session on line, log in to www.craigtuckerlcsw.com and go to 'My Appointments'\r\n";

            $this->email->message($msg);
            $this->email->send();
            $msg = "";
            echo $this->email->print_debugger();  
        }
    }
}
}
/* End of file reminders.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/cli/reminders.php */
```

Comment: Thank you so much for those who help! I am pretty new to coding and am having trouble learning this one, any help is very much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: what's the difference between every minute and once a day? did you really ask that?

Comment: I know the difference between the two, but I was wondering what the difference was within cron. Will it only send when it's run once a day, or if it's ran every minute will it just spam the SMS. etc.

Comment: I have a webservice which does a similar thing to this. My SMS provider lets you specify the time you want the SMS to be sent so I just run the cron job once a day and submit all SMS for that day in one go, with the sending times set according to the appointment time

Comment: @miknik what do you mean by SMS provider? Is it a paid service to send the SMS? Also, how did you structure the cron job?

Comment: I don't know of any free SMS sending services. My SMS provider is Messagebird who charge about 2.5c each. Looking at your code it seems like its getting all appointments for set days in the future, so you only want to run it once a day otherwise it will send multiple reminders to the same people. A cron job is just a command line input to be executed automatically. I wrote my SMS reminder script in PHP and my cron entry just looks like this 0 9 * * * php /path/to/script/scriptname.php 2> /dev/null

Comment: @miknik would it be free if I do it through the php mail function? So, finding out their cell provider then using the free email address for each cell provider and sending it that way? Would that work?

Comment: No idea, we dont have free sms email addresses here in the UK. How will you look up the cell providers for free? If you send a lot I guess they might realise and ban you as all your emails will originate from the same IP. If cost is an issue why not send email reminders (10,000 free/month with mailgun api, and you can set delivery time)? Or add push notifications to your website? Free email SMS gateway probably won't look very professional to your users